# Log into a site using PHP's HttpRequest?

Tags: php, httprequest, linkedin-api

I'm looking for a way to search for business "X" on LinkedIn, which requires a valid login session. I'm making Http requests with PHP's HttpRequest object, but I'm not familiar enough with handling session data/cookies to figure out how to pinpoint my mistake.

```
    $loginURL = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit";
    $loginPostData = array("session_key" => "mylogin@mydomain.com",
                           "session_password" => "itsasecret",
                           "source_app" => "",
                           "signin" => "",
                           "session_redirect" => "",
                           "csrfToken" => "",
                           "sourceAlias" => "",
    );

    $httpRequest = new HttpRequest($loginURL, HttpRequest::METH_POST);
    $httpRequest->setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    $httpRequest->addPostFields($loginPostData);
    $httpRequest->setOptions(array("redirect" => 10));
    $httpMessage = $httpRequest->send();
    $responseBody = $httpMessage->getBody());
```

I write $responseBody to a file and open it in a browser, but it only contains a generic LinkedIn page with log in fields. Using the "Tamper Data" extension to firefix, I can see that the following request headers allow firefox to load a session-viewable webpage:

```
Host=www.linkedin.com
Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length=124
POSTDATA=source_app=&session_key=mylogin@mydomain.com&session_password=itsasecret&signin=&session_redirect=&csrfToken=&sourceAlias=
```

There's something weird about the data I get back too: I'd expect to see something like "invalid username or password", but I get the default linkedin.com page.

Comment: Are you stuck with HttpRequest?  Can you use `curl`?

Comment: I would prefer to use HttpRequest, since I'm set up for it already and I have no experience with curl in PHP.

Comment: I've also substituted the "@" in my username with "%40" to no effect

Comment: Would using the API be an option? The company api would do exactly what you are looking for in terms of looking up specific companies, etc.

Comment: Is there a way to log in with the API? I took a look at it, but it was clearly made with a different purpose in mind. When I was checking it out I couldn't see any way to log in with an account through the API. If you could provide a working example that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Actually looking at the code of linkedin there are some hidden input that you need to send as POST datas, because your request has not one or more of these values you got the same login page...

Copy & paste from linkedin

```
 <input type="hidden" name="source_app" value="">
 <input type="hidden" name="trk" value="guest_home_login">
 <input type="hidden" name="session_redirect" value="" id="session_redirect-login"><input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" value="ajax:9034582961576232024" id="csrfToken-login"><input type="hidden" name="sourceAlias" value="0_7r5yezRXCiA_H0CRD8sf6DhOjTKUNps5xGTqeX8EEoi" id="sourceAlias-login">
```

Comment: I did notice the hidden fields - I've been experimenting, and I meant to include those values in my question. I'll update the Q